# Scrollbar is hidden on desktop website and doesn't scroll, while it works on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css

I have written some code to display a list of users inside a `div` with HTML and CSS, but it doesn't show the bottom scrollbar, although the area scrolls horizontally on mobile browsers.

**JavaScript** - this function calls the code above form my `index.php` page:

```
function queryTopUsers() {
        console.log('LAT: ' + latitude + ' -- LNG: ' + longitude);

        $.ajax({
            url:'query-top-users.php',
            data: 'lat=' + latitude + '&lng=' + longitude,
            type: 'GET',
            success:function(data) {
                document.getElementById("topUsersGrid").innerHTML = data;
                console.log(data);
            }, 
            // error
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText;
                swal("Ouch!", errorMessage, "error");
        }});
    }
```

**HTML** - There's a simple custom div in my `index.php` page where the code echoed by the PHP code gets displayed:

```
<div id="topUsersGrid">
   <div class="top-user">
         <div class="text-center" style="width: 130px">
            <a href="user-profile.php?upObjID=123">
               <div class="top-profile-pic"> 
                  <img src="{img-link}">
               </div><br>
               <strong style="font-size: 14px">Username</strong>
           </a>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** - This code is to design my `#topUsersGrid` div:

```
#topUsersGrid {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.top-user {
   width: 45px;
   float: none;
   margin: 0 60px;
   display: inline-block;
   zoom: 1;
}
.top-user a {
   transition: ease .3s;
}
.top-user a:hover {
   text-decoration: none;
   letter-spacing: 1.0px;
   color: #000;
}

.top-profile-pic {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 120px;
   height: 120px;
   overflow:hidden;
   border-radius: 100px;
   border: 3px solid #e1e1e1;
}

.top-profile-pic img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

And here's the result on a desktop browser - Chrome, Firefox, Safari:

[image: topUsersGrid on desktop browser]

So, as you can see, there's no bottom scrollbar visible, I cannot scroll that area horizontally to see other users. If I load the same index page on my device's browser, I can scroll that area with my finger, left and right.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, maybe in the CSS, maybe because the code gets echoed by PHP instead of being present in the index page.

Comment: Show us just the rendered HTML that is created by the PHP/JS.

Comment: @disinfor do you mean the website’s url?

Comment: No, post the HTML markup that the PHP creates when you view the URL - basically everything in the `<div id="topUsersGrid"></div>` I don't think the PHP or JS matter for this question - only what the PHP renders.

Comment: to present your php here in the question isn´t necessary.... and i don´t know what you put in the variables `$USER_AVATAR` and `$USER_USERNAME` to obtain the users info, but normally you would place (in that case) strings to get that informations.

Comment: i showed the php code just to let you know what generates the proper html code that goes inside the topUsersGrid div, the screenshot shows data, i just cannot display the bottom scrollbar

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
#topUsersGrid {
overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

You might need to give a max width to that div such as:

```
#topUsersGrid {
max-width: 500px;
overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: overflow-x: scroll; is already present, so should i add a max-width only?

Comment: Yep! I would also set the `max-width` to `100vw` or `calc(100vw = <extra space>`.

Comment: @TheWebDeveloperBlog and MistaPrime - it doesn't work, no bottom scrollbar visible, I cannot scroll with the mouse.

Comment: For the scroll to appear the contents of the #topUsersGrid need to be longer than your max-width of 500px. If it still fails try to send us the HTML to the #topUsersGrid with all of it's contents.

Comment: Please check this website: https://trendiyo.com/index.php - you can see the page source

Comment: In that link the #topUsersGrid div has no contents. It is empty. It needs to have contents for it to scroll.

Comment: I know, that's what I said, the JS function calls the code of a separate PHP file, and that file echoes the code that goes inside the #topUserGrid div. If you use Chrome and open the Inspect -> Elements tab, you'll see the div's content, check it out.

Comment: Not sure where to look, it shows empty, see screenshot: http://screenshot.how/QTZfMM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200398/discussion-between-xscoder-and-mistaprime).

Comment: @MistaPrime and xscoder The list of users trendiyo.com/index.php works on my browser. It scrolls perfectly! (I'm using Chrome on MacOS)